# Cannot produce Glossaries in Latex

Tags: latex

I'm havin trouble printing my glossary and acronym directory with the `glossaries` package. It produces an empty page where I call `\makeglossaries`. I suspect biber, babel or my build directory might be interfering with it.

My `main.tex` looks something like this:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}

\setacronymstyle{long-short}
\shorthandoff{"}
\makeglossaries

\addbibresource{head/bibliography.bib}
\loadglsentries{head/glossary}

\begin{document}
    ...40 pages of actual content about \gls{acr:ipd} and 
    \gls{BIM} and even more \gls{acr:ipd}...
    \printglossaries
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

With `glossary.tex` in the directory `head`:

```
\newglossaryentry{BIM}{name={Building Information Modeling},description={3D and shit. \lipsum}}
\newacronym{acr:ipd}{IPD}{Integrated Project Delivery}
```

Packages that I'm pretty sure are irelevant are omitted for brevity.

I have configured TexStudio to run the following sequence:

```
pdflatex.exe -src -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -aux-directory=build main.tex
makeglossaries.exe -d build main
biber.exe --input_directory build --output_directory build main
pdflatex.exe -src -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -aux-directory=build main.tex
pdflatex.exe -src -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -aux-directory=build main.tex
```

The problem appears to be that makeglossaries doesn't actually do anything. All it logs is

```
makeglossaries version 4.41 (2018-07-23)
Changed to 'build'
```

No files are changed when I run makeglossaries manually. I have manually added the Perl directory to ENV; it is reachable from my working directory. I have tried swiching to xindy and back according to the documentation, but to no avail. I have switched the order of biber and makeglossaries. I deleted the `build` directory after every attempt.

What is going wrong?

**Update**: I have confirmed that makeglossaries does in fact do nothing. Running the MWE in a separate directory yielded the desired results and much more verbose console output from makeglossaries.

Comment: Did you try your MWE? Do you see the same problem with it? Did you check what happens if you run `makeglossaries` with `-n`? Do you have makeindex and/or xindy available?

Comment: Yes, I did try the MWE in another directory. To my suprise, it works without issue (I guess it's not a proper MWE then). 
`-n` has no effect. 
Whether I use Xindy or not has no effect.

Comment: You could try to build that MWE within the same directory to see whenever the directory is the problem. If it is not you know that one of the other packages seems to be interfering.

Comment: After copying the entire directory to another location and renaming the main file to something other than `main` without effect I have ruled out the path as source of the issue. It's probably some other package but I didn't have the patience to figure out which one.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the `makeglossaries` script is the issue. It just didn't do anything. No idea why. Luckily, it isn't supposed to do much more than call `Xindy` or `Makeindex`. I solved the issue by bypassing it with a file called `build.bat`:

```
pdflatex.exe -src -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -aux-directory=build main.tex
xindy  -L german -C din5007-utf8 -I xindy -M "build\main" -t "build\main.glg" -o "build\main.gls" "build\main.glo"
biber.exe --input_directory build --output_directory build main
pdflatex.exe -src -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -aux-directory=build main.tex
pdflatex.exe -src -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -aux-directory=build main.tex
```

Because I like working with TexStudio, I have set the second line as the makeglossaries command in the configuration and continuing with my regular build sequence.